# Asset helpers with inline CSS in Rails view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm just adapting template code to a Rails web app.

I've got inline CSS referencing image assets like this:

```
  <div class="head" style="background-image: url('../somepath/b43.jpg');">
```

I'd like to store and reference images in the asset pipeline. I've used helpers like `image_path` before, but only in Sass files.

How do I write code that looks something like:

```
  <div class="head" style="background-image: url(image_path('b43.jpg'));">
```

that the inline CSS (using Rails asset helper) gets emitted with actual image asset folder paths when the page is rendered?

Right now, I'm just getting:

```
  <div class="head" style="background-image: url(image_path('b43.jpg'));">
```

in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use inline erb style for this

```
<div class="head" 
     style="background-image: url(<%= image_path('b43.jpg') %>);">
```

Comment: Thanks @Iceman. I did this and got: `<div class="head" style="background-image: url:('/images/b32.jpg');">`.

I need to reference `/assets/background/b32-somefingerprint.jpg`.

My other `image_tag` helpers in my ERB correctly reference the asset path (e.g. `image_path "avatar1.jpg"` yields `/assets/avatars/avatar1-somefingerprint.jpg` or `image_path "b1.jpg"` yields `/assets/blog/b1.jpg`).

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, the asset helper should automatically reference the correct file.

Comment: You say you need `/assets/background`, if the image is in the `background` folder you'll need to do `image_path('background/b32.jpg')`